# Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and $a\in G$. Define $x\ast y:=x\cdot a \cdot y$. Show $(G,\ast)$ is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group with operation $\cdot$  and let $a \in G$. Define a new operation $*$ on the set $G$ by $x*y$ = $x·a·y$ for all $x,y \in G$. Show $G$ is a group under the operation $*$.

Does this group under the operation have an inverse?

I know you need to use $x*b = a^{-1}$ and $b*x = a^{-1}$. But I am not getting them to have the same result.

So far I have
$b*x = bax$ so $bax = a^{-1}$
and
$x*b = xab$ so $xab = a^{-1}$.

Comment: What do you get, if you first solve $x$ from the equation $bax=a^{-1}$, and then from the equation $xab=a^{-1}$? Do you get the same answer?

Comment: Yes. Then G under the operation * has an inverse.

Comment: Ok, so have checked all the group axioms now?

Comment: "Does this group under the operation have an inverse?" is a strange question. It probably should read: does every element of $G$ have an inverse for the operation "$*$", and the answer must be "yes" since that is part of showing that $(G,{*})$ is a group.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look at $x=a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

If possible, let x' be the inverse(left as well as right) of x in G. then by def we have
x*x'=x'*x=e, e=1 be the identity in G.
Now,
x*x'=e
=>xax'=1, where a∈G
=>x'=x−1a−1
Similarly, x'*x=e
=>x'ax=1, where a∈G
=>x'=x−1a−1
Hence for a element in G its inverse exists in G.